# Getting the height of HTML Content

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am loading an html file in to an UIWebView. Now I want to know that is there any way I can get height of the contents being load in the UIWebView?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight"] integerValue];
```

Try [this site](http://www.mensus.net/browser/inter.shtml) for `document.body.offsetHeight` alternatives.  The best choice probably depends on your page, what you want to measure and when you are measuring.